# Estimate Spark memory requirement for my input data

Tags: apache-spark

Given an untyped `Dataset`, how does Spark store the `Row`s which contains the actual data?
My hunch is that it's a `Map`, but I cannot find any code reference.

```
root
 |-- firstname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lastname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- age: integer (nullable = true)
```

I'm asking this because we have a dynamic dataset processing and I'm trying to estimate the needed memory based on the input data.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many variables (swapping, multiple steps in the execution plan, spark auto optimizations, caching, ...) to estimate the way you're thinking to estimate.

From [official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#determining-memory-consumption):

> ***Determining Memory Consumption***
>
> *The best way to size the amount of memory consumption a dataset will require is to create an RDD, put it into cache, and look at the “Storage” page in the web UI. The page will tell you how much memory the RDD is occupying.*
>
> *To estimate the memory consumption of a particular object, use SizeEstimator’s estimate method. This is useful for experimenting with different data layouts to trim memory usage, as well as determining the amount of space a broadcast variable will occupy on each executor heap.*

Check out the [Spark UI](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/web-ui.html). See [stage details](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/web-ui.html#stage-detail), which has some stats related to memory usage including "Peak execution memory".

[image]

---

You also get very detailed and [fine-grained metrics](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#source--jvm-source). You can send that to your own monitoring tool like Datadog/Loki/... and perform more analytics to get more concrete ideas.

Comment: That gives an idea of a current usage. What I want to know is how I can estimate usage.
Example I have is that we have XX million rows. The total number of columns across all rows is 200.
At any point each row actually only has up to 3 columns populated and others being null.
What is the memory footprint of each row during processing? Is it dependent on the `200` number or `3`?

In reality it's not this simple, there are variations, but I don't even know conceptually how to approach this in Spark.

Comment: "There are too many variables.....". Idea is to extrapolate from test results of a smaller representative data sample. Updated the answer with some more official recs.

Comment: Extrapolation has not worked well for our usecase. Once it fails, the job introduces latency or outright fails. 
We know why - the input data is not predictable.
The question is, since we know what the data is at the time of processing it and we have stats from logs, how can we use that set the correct machine counts.
For us to be able to do that, we need to know how various elements impact the Spark. The last factor we are having trouble with is understanding how underlying `row` object is represented in memory - which is what the question is about.